# Scrolling an editable spark TextArea from Flex Hero Mobile on a touch device

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, blackberry-playbook, flex4.5

I am having a hard time figuring this out...

How do you scroll an editable TextArea (Flex Hero) on a touch device?
I am referring to the situation where the text does not fit in the TextArea height.
When I try to tap and drag the text gets selected and not scrolled... Am I missing a something here? I am using verticalScrollPolicy = on (also tried auto).

I am testing the code in the Blackberry Playbook simulator (my targeted device for my app).

If you have any hints or suggestions please let me know.

Thanks,

Comment: What build of the Flex Hero SDK are you using?

Answer (score 0):

A TextArea is an editable component.  You should try using RichText instead if you don't want to edit the text.

Comment: Thing is, I want the user to be able to enter text in the text area and if the text becomes taller than the screen, obviously the user should be able to scroll.  I would also settle for a way of limiting the input to the height of the text-area so that no scroll is needed. Is there a way to limit the number of lines a user can input in a text-area?

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a s:Scroller:

```
<s:Scroller id="prayerSc" width="100%" height="100%">
<s:RichEditableText id="prayerText" width="100%" height="100%" clipAndEnableScrolling="true" selectable="true" editable="true" textFlow="{PTFL}" />
</s:Scroller>
```

Answer (score 0):

RichEditableText is not optimized for mobile

Use this instead [Orig source](http://devgirl.org/2010/12/16/automatically-scroll-flex-mobile-textarea/)

```
import spark.components.supportClasses.MobileTextField;
private var cnt:int = 0;

protected function addText():void
{
            ta.appendText('More text... ' + cnt++ + '\n');
            MobileTextField(ta.textDisplay).scrollV++;
}

<s:TextArea id="ta" width="95%" height="200" editable="false"/>
```